# E-mail validation for signup form

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a newsletter signup field with some Javascript that will show an error is the field is blank when the button is pressed and a success message when it is not.  This code works perfectly fine, but I want to add the ability to validate the e-mail address as well without any success.

Here is the HTML markup:

```
<style>
        .error {color: #fff; text-align: left;}
        .hide {display: none !important;;}
        .show {display: block !important;}
</style>

<div>
    <div class="max-w-3xl text-center mx-auto">
        <h2 class="text-xl text-center normal-case">Get The VIP Treatment</h2>
        <p class="text-lg text-center">Join the Whittard family to receive access to exciting promotions, new products, recipes, competitions, and more.</p>
    <div>
    <!-- Form elements go here: Style as you wish -->

    <div id="newsletter-signup">
    <table class="mb-0">
        <tbody class="bg-[#3F5562] border-none grid grid-cols-1">
            <p id="newsletter-confirmation" class="text-lg text-center hidden">Thank you for signing up!</p>
        <tr class="w-full font-['AvenirLTStd-Medium'] text-base bg-[#3F5562] block">
            <th class="hidden">Email address</th>

            <td class="font-['AvenirLTStd-Medium'] text-base block pb-0">
                <input id="email" class="mb-0" name="ue" type="text" value="" placeholder="Email address*" required />
                <p id="newsletter-no-email" class="text-lg text-center m-0 hidden">Please enter a valid e-mail address</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input id="signupbutton" class="signup hover:bg-[#14679e] hover:ease-out hover:cursor-pointer text-white max-w-[200px] bg-[#435764] font-normal font-['AvenirLTStd-Medium'] border border-solid border-[#8196a1] rounded-sm tracking-wider transition duration-300 ease-in text-lg px-6 py-2 mt-2" type="submit" value="Sign Up" style="padding: 5px 20px;" name="submit" />
</div>
    <!-- End of form elements -->
</form>
```

Here is my current Javascript:

```
<script>
    //Newsletter Confirmation
    document.querySelector ( '#signupbutton' ).addEventListener('click',function() {
            if( document.querySelector('#email').value.length == 0) {
            document.querySelector( '#newsletter-no-email' ).classList.toggle( 'show' );         
            }else{
            document.querySelector('#email').classList.toggle('hide');
            document.querySelector( '#newsletter-no-email' ).classList.toggle( 'hide' );
            document.querySelector( '#newsletter-confirmation' ).classList.toggle( 'show' );
            document.querySelector( '#newsletter-no-email' ).classList.toggle( 'hide' );  
        document.querySelector( '#newsletter-no-email' ).classList.remove( 'show' );  
            }
        });

</script>
```

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
<script>
    //Newsletter Confirmation
    document.querySelector ( '#signupbutton' ).addEventListener('click',function() {
            if( document.querySelector('#email').value.length == 0 || document.querySelector('#email').value == /^(([^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@(([^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+\.)+[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]{2,})$/iu ) {
            document.querySelector( '#newsletter-no-email' ).classList.toggle( 'show' );         
            }else{
            document.querySelector('#email').classList.toggle('hide');
            document.querySelector( '#newsletter-no-email' ).classList.toggle( 'hide' );
            document.querySelector( '#newsletter-confirmation' ).classList.toggle( 'show' );
            document.querySelector( '#newsletter-no-email' ).classList.toggle( 'hide' );  
            document.querySelector( '#newsletter-no-email' ).classList.remove( 'show' );  
            }
        });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular expression needs to be tested against the value of the email input, not compared to it.

```
<script>
    //Newsletter Confirmation
    document.querySelector('#signupbutton').addEventListener('click', function() {
        const email = document.querySelector('#email').value;
        const emailRegex = /^(([^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@(([^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+\.)+[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]{2,})$/iu;
        if (email.length == 0 || !emailRegex.test(email)) {
//More code
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, however I had to make a modification to show the reject message, I added this after the if query:    
document.querySelector( '#newsletter-no-email' ).classList.toggle( 'show' );